# Pause music on middle click at sound-indicator

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, xfce, indicator-sound, xfce-panel

Is it possible to change middle-click action of sound indicator? I want to be able to pause/resume playback of gmusicbrowser by middle-clicking (or using another mouse combo) on it.

Current behavior on middle click: mute/unmute.

I'm aware that I can click on indicator then press play button, but I'm too lazy to do this :)

I am using Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I think this depends on the player. Clementine supports it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with player. I'm asking about sound indicator. Many players support this, yes. But I'm talking about default sound indicator of panel, which has integration with player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that short answer is no.

Source code:

```
static void
indicator_sound_middle_click (IndicatorObject * io, IndicatorObjectEntry * entry,
                              guint time, gpointer data)
{
  IndicatorSoundPrivate* priv = INDICATOR_SOUND_GET_PRIVATE(io);
  g_return_if_fail (priv);

  mute_widget_toggle(priv->mute_widget);
}
```

Comment: actually, I posted indicator-sound-gtk source by mistake, but in indicator-sound package mute action is also hard-coded. But it can be rebuilded with "indicator.mute" action changed to "indicator.play.${player-id}"